# Argument Out of Range Exception - Website Checking

Tags: c#, image, exception

I am working on an application that checks if a website is up, by checking if specific words are being shown. In the code provided, I make an image appear (green if website is up, red if down), but I must delete this image when the timer checks the website again. I get the following error for `StkPan_Icons.Children.RemoveAt(RefNum);`

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Any Help?

```
private void ClearImageStack(int RefNum)
{
    StkPan_Icons.Children.RemoveAt(RefNum);
}


private void GetSiteAndCompare(int URL_Num)
{
    using (var Client = new WebClient())
    {
        string SiteContent = Client.DownloadString("http://" + UrlArrary[URL_Num]);

        if (SiteContent.Contains(CheckForArray[URL_Num]))
        {
            StkPan_Icons.Children.Insert(URL_Num, GetGreen());
            FailRefArray[URL_Num] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            StkPan_Icons.Children.Insert(URL_Num, GetRed());
            Fail(URL_Num);
        }
    }
}

private void RunCheck()
{
    // Checks all the websites.
    for (int i = 0; i < URLCount; i++)
    {
        ClearImageStack(i);
        GetSiteAndCompare(i);
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `RefNum` and how many elements are in `StkPan_Icons.Children`?  I'm guessing those two values don't match...

Comment: I am not referencing `RefNum` anywhere but in the code example. Does it not have a value? And there are 3 elements in `StkPan_Icons.Children`

Comment: It's an `int` so it always has a value.  Where do you call `ClearImageStack()`?  That's where you're giving it a value.

Comment: I will add it to the code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your loop logic doesn't make sense for editing that collection.  Think about a simplified example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    someCollection.RemoveAt(i);
```

If `someCollection` initially has 3 elements, this code is going to result in an error.  It's trying to do the following to the collection:

1. Remove the element at index 0 (the collection now has 2 elements)
2. Remove the element at index 1 (the collection now has 1 element)
3. Remove the element at index 2 (**Error: The collection has only one element, there is no index 2**)

If you want to just clear the collection (as implied by the function name) then you don't need to loop through its elements.  It *probably* has a `.Clear()` function on it already.  Try something like this:

```
StkPan_Icons.Children.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < URLCount; i++)
    GetSiteAndCompare(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused. (I am new to C#), I tried the clear(); function from your example, but I get thrown a XAML error :(

Comment: @Andrew: What's the error?  It might be unrelated to this particular issue and be worth an entirely new question.  (Note: I don't know much if anything about XAML.  The error you were receiving in the question was just in C#, no UI technologies involved.)

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of issues. You need to add bounds checking to both ClearImageStack and the method that calls it. I.e.

```
private void ClearImageStack(int refNum)
{
    if (StkPan_Icons.Children.Count() <= refNum) // or .Length depending on the type
        StkPan_Icons.Children.RemoveAt(refNum);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Really, bitch?")
}
```

The root cause though is that URLCount in RunCheck has a different (higher) value than StkPan_Icons.Children.Count(). It makes me wonder why you aren't doing something like

```
private void RunCheck()
{
    // Checks all the websites.
    for (int i = 0; i < StkPan_Icons.Children.Count(); i++)
    {
        ClearImageStack(i);
        GetSiteAndCompare(i);
    }

    UpdateStatus();
}
```